# How does the string replace function in VB.net not work?

Tags: vb.net

I wrote up some code. The code is shown below. The first part is to read a html into string format. The second part is to search a mark in the string and replace the string by other string.

The 1st part (I test it many times, it works fine)

```
Public Function ReadTextFile(ByVal TextFileName As String) As String
    Dim TempString As String
    Dim StreamToDisplay As StreamReader
    StreamToDisplay = New StreamReader(TextFileName)
    TempString = StreamToDisplay.ReadToEnd
    StreamToDisplay.Close()
    Return TempString
End Function
```

The 2nd part (I test it many times, the search and replace does not work. I checked many times that the "TempText" DOES contain string. The "the_key_string" DOES inside the "TempText" String. I check it by using QuickWatch in VB.net. However, the replace function does NOT do its job)

```
            Dim TextPath = C:xxxxxx
            TempText = ReadTextFile(TextPath)
            TempText.Replace("the_key_string", "replace_by_this_string")
```

Please help. I have no clue where I made the mistake

Comment: Strings are immutable, you need to re-assign `TempText` from the result of Replace.

Answer (score 15):

[`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) returns new string instead of modifying the source one. You have to assign it back to your variable:

```
TempText = TempText.Replace("the_key_string", "replace_by_this_string")
```

From MSDN:

> **Returns a new string** in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

Answer (score 5):

Strings are immutable, that means once they are created you cannot modify them. So you have to create a new one and assign that to your string variable:

```
TempText = TempText.Replace("the_key_string", "replace_by_this_string")
```

MSDN: [`String Data Type (Visual Basic)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/thwcx436.aspx):

> Once you assign a string to a String variable, that string is
>   immutable, which means you cannot change its length or contents. When
>   you alter a string in any way, Visual Basic creates a new string and
>   abandons the previous one. The String variable then points to the new
>   string.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the value to something, like :

```
TempText = TempText.Replace("the_key_string", "replace_by_this_string")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is performing the string replace, but it's not putting the *result* of it anywhere:

```
TempText.Replace("the_key_string", "replace_by_this_string")
```

You need to assign the result to something:

```
TempText = TempText.Replace("the_key_string", "replace_by_this_string")
```

Answer (score 0):

The Replace method returns the modified string.

You need something like this:

```
Dim TextPath = C:xxxxxx
TempText = ReadTextFile(TextPath)
Dim ModifiedString as String
ModifiedString = TempText.Replace("the_key_string", "replace_by_this_string")
```

Answer (score 0):

"this is a string"
If you do Replace 'string' with 'whatever' this string should be: "this is a whatever". so what you can do is put that in a new string. how? replace method returns a string so, it is easy :)
see this: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try these and one might work.  i think that it is the underscore.

TempText.Replace("thekeystring", "replace_by_this_string")

TempText.Replace("the key string", "replace_by_this_string")

TempText.Replace("the__key__string", "replace_by_this_string")